# Show last item in ListiView when you click on edit text

Tags: android

currently I'm doing this to get the focus of the last item in a listview after clicking on an edit text:

```
    bodyText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {               
            getListView().setSelection(getListView().getCount());
        }
    });

    bodyText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            getListView().setSelection(getListView().getCount());
        }
    });
```

It works great and grabs the last item, problem is the soft keypad appears and covers the last 3 items in the listview. Is there a way to show the last item AFTER the soft keypad appears and resizes the screen? Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I made my own Custom ListView like this:

```
public class CustomListView extends ListView {

public CustomListView (Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomListView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomListView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int xNew, int yNew, int xOld, int yOld) {
    super.onSizeChanged(xNew, yNew, xOld, yOld);

    setSelection(getCount());

}
}
```

You must include all 3 constructors or an exception will be thrown.

Then in the XML where you usually put

**ListView**

```
android:id="@+id/android:list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Change **ListView** to **com.blah.blah.CustomListView**.

Sorry for the messy layout, for some reason I can't get the formatter to properly work.

Run your application. Now when you click on the EditText, it shows the last item AFTER the soft keyboard shows! Note that there are some limitations like when the auto-complete function appears when you type text in the EditText, it will show the last item as well due to a change in size of the ListView.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

The solution offered by @Maurice is almost correct (or at least it almost works for me). I had to modify the onSizeChanged method to put the setSelection into a call to post, as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int xNew, int yNew, int xOld, int yOld) {
    super.onSizeChanged(xNew, yNew, xOld, yOld);

    post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            setSelection(getCount());
        }
    });
}
```

Per [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29), post "Causes the Runnable to be added to the message queue. The runnable will be run on the user interface thread." This is also a technique used in some of the Android AbsListView source.

Comment: I have only one question, why aren't u using getCount()-1 ?

Comment: In my actual implementation I record the index of the last item clicked and scroll to that. You can use getCount()-1 or whatever approach makes sense for your implementation.

Comment: since the data source index starts from 0.
lets say a list or an array for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<activity
.....
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

in your manifest file.

Comment: <activity android:name=".MessageList" android:theme="@style/TallTitle"
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
  </activity> I have this in my Manifest already, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For Someone who works with new RecyclerView widget that is recommended:

just like accepted answer but replace:

```
setSelection(getCount());
```

with this:

```
 (LinearLayoutManager)getLayoutManager())
.scrollToPositionWithOffset(getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1, 0);
```

just `LinearLayoutManager`and `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` have this method. so use this `LayoutManagers`.