# AutocompleteTextView not showing complete suggestions while showing keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, autocompletetextview, bottom-sheet

I am using an AutoCompleteTextview in one bottom sheet. While typing in the AutoCompleteTextview it is not showing complete suggestions because of he keyboard. In Emulater while we are using hardware keyboard it is showing popup. How can we resolve this? This is how it looks.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133706/push-listview-when-keyboard-appears-without-adjustpan...
This might help you...

Comment: Did you get a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to disable keybord, you can do it programatically like this

```
public void removeKeyboard(EditText e, Context context){
InputMethodManager keyB = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
keyB.hideSoftInputFromWindow(e.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

where EditText e or may be some other view calling for text input