# Edit Text in ListActivity ListView loses focus when keyboard comes up

Tags: android, listview, focus, android-edittext, listactivity

I have searched and searched for an answer to this question and everything that looked like an answer has not worked so I guess I will just ask.

I have a couple of `EditText` boxes added to a `ListView` that is the basis to a `ListActivity`.  When I set the `windowSoftInputMode` to `adjustPan` and click in an `EditText` it works until you click on it again and then the keyboard covers it up.  When I use `adjustResize` it works except when the keyboard comes up the `EditText` loses focus and I have to tap on it again to type.

I was trying to figure out how to catch the `onResize` but that seems to be associated with the View and not the activity and I'm not entirely sure how to listen for it.  I have also tried all sorts of focusable settings on the `EditText` boxes and the `ListView` itself (as suggested in other posts I read) that don't seem to help either.

Comment: Is it possible to show a screenshot of what it looks like? Also some code might be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Focusable EditText inside ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

All you really need to do is apply this to your ListView:

**XML:**

```
android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
```

**Java:**

```
listView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
```

Comment: Oh my goodness thank you! This came back around as a bigger problem today and so I just saw this answer and it seems to work!

Comment: So this solution mostly works. Problem is that the first focusable edit box always gets selected when the SIP comes up. This is a problem if the edit box I'm trying to select isn't the first focusable one. Still trying to work out how to catch this which puts me in a similar place to where I was. Is there a way to set a view's focus order to be first even if it isn't first in the layout?

Comment: I have no idea why all the other SO answers recommend `beforeDescendants`. `afterDescendants` is the only one that's worked for me, and also makes perfect sense in terms of the docs.

Comment: thanks a lot , makes me wonder ,why android doesnt do this automatically or provide hints in studio for the same
Also this problem is quite common but is not recognised in attention

Comment: @AbhishekMathur studio is not awere that this view is used in a ListView / RecyclerView

Answer (score 2):

For me a combination of the following helped me (especially number 3):

1) Add the following to the related Activity in the manifest file, this is required for your ListView to be resized to fill only the area above the softKeyboard:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

2) With the below the ListView will ONLY get focus only if none of its descendants want it. The descendants (the EditText) needs to get and keep focus.

```
<ListView
...
android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"/>
```

3) The automatic showing/hiding of the Spelling Suggestions bar right above the keyboard keeps triggering the ListView to refresh. I turned the Suggestions off for any EditText in my ListView.

```
<EditText
...
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword" />
```

Answer (score 2):

recycler view works best and no need to mess around with any other properties anywhere.

Comment: I agree.  I tried EVERYTHING to fix the behaviour of `EditText` in `ListView`, and NOTHING worked.  I migrated to using `RecyclerView` (see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) and it all works like a dream, with no nasty hacks.  And the migration was easy because I was already using the `ViewHolder` model in my `ListView` adapter.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it perfect worked with adding this like of code to manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried after you do `adjustResize` making sure to reset the focus to the `EditText` by doing something like `EditText.requestFocus();` so that it has focus again and the user doesn't have to tap it again. you can use `EditText.isFocused()` to see if it is focused (true) or not (false) in a debugging log statement or something as well.

you might need to set the field to `focusable` as well using `SetFocusable()` but be careful because this could potentially take away the focus from the `ListView` itself and prevent you from being able to scroll or select things later so you will have to play around with the setting focusable and is focused stuff.

Comment: I was looking into trying to catch the onResize but as it is associated with the view not the activity I'm not entirely sure how to do it.  I tried a lot of different variations of setting the focus that I got from other similar questions but none of them seem to help.

Comment: perhaps it would be better to not resize the keyboard and instead move your edittext somewhere that will be above the keyboard? Is there a specific reason you need the textbox where it is?

Comment: Yes, that is the specified design.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced exactly the same issue in my project.

To resolve the issue I have subclassed the `EditText` and handled the "Back" button press - to make sure that my `EditText`clears focus at that moment.

Check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321968/show-last-item-in-listiview-when-you-click-on-edit-text), on how to do it.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
mViewHolder.editText = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            mViewHolder.editText.setTag(position);
            mViewHolder.editText.setTextColor(0xFF000000);
            mViewHolder.editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if (!hasFocus) {
                        EditText et =(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                        editTextArrayList.set(position,et.getText().toString().trim());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Hi below link may help for you http://mylearnandroid.blogspot.in/2014/06/listview-problem-while-scrolling.html