# EditText Loses Focus on Click

Tags: android, android-edittext, adapter

I'm writing an activity to list a bunch of items from the database and show an additional column with a quantity. I implemented an ArrayAdapter to show my custom layout.
Here is the code of the most important parts of the Adapter:

```
static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView text;
    protected EditText editText;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rowquantitylayout, null);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
        viewHolder.editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        viewHolder.editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Editable:" + s.toString());
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int count, int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int before, int count) {
            }
        });
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.editText.setTag(list.get(position));
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).editText.setTag(list.get(position));
    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getDescription());
    holder.editText.setText("" + list.get(position).getQuantity());
    return view;

}
```

Now, when I try to focus the "EditText" it loses focus just after I clicked it. It shows the keboard and it even gets to the Log.i, but doesnt let me change the value since it is not focused.

Thanks for the help

Comment: have you tried to set property like this on edittext android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Focusable EditText inside ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview)

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem and I searched for an answer.
Here is an answer to a similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/9338694/1448661

You have to put a line in your activity in the manifest :

```
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

And your listview must have this line too :

```
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```

And now you will probably face another problem which is the lost of your text when scrolling. If this happens take a look at this tutorial :
http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/

Hope this will help.
Goui

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this as soon as posible. How come such a simple and common task is so complicated?

Comment: I found another same solution on stackoverflow, but descendantFocusability is afterDescendants. 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15294709/1799322

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textShortMessage" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: Still not working. I don't know if it helps bit the edit text is inside a relative layout