# EditText loses focus onTextChange

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working on an Android application built using [Anvil](https://github.com/zserge/anvil) and Kotlin, and currently I've got a RecyclerView rendering a list of key-value pairs that should be editable by the user. In order to save these edits, I've added an `onTextChanged` listener as follows:

```
textInputLayout {
  size(MATCH, WRAP)
  /* ommitted style attributes */

  editText {
    size(MATCH, WRAP)
    /* ommitted style attributes */
    init {
      text(getPropertyValue(item))
      onTextChanged { onPropertyChange(item.first, it.toString()) }
    }
  }
}
```

In the above example, `item` is of type `Pair<String, Property>` where `Property` is a custom object that gives information about format type (string, date, number, etc.) and the `getPropertyValue` call has the signature `getPropertyValue(item: Pair<String, Property>): String`.

For some reason, every time I type the text field sees no changes but loses focus. The `onTextChanged` listener is definitely getting called because when it executes I can see the updated values produced by `onPropertyChange` getting logged to the console.

I've already tried the solutions outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14910131/edittext-loses-focus-on-click) to no avail. Does anyone have any other suggestions? Been stuck on this for  a while now.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is a bug in Anvil, as using Android's `onTextChanged` implementation works properly. Closing this and I'll file a bug in their repo.