# Prevent from changing editText on keyboard open

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

In my Android application, I have ListView, with header contains 2 `editText`. When I try to focus on lower `editText`, the keyboard shows up, and changes focus to upper editText. Header layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:hint="Title"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:nextFocusUp="@id/name"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Wordpack description"
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/description"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:id="@+id/locale"
        android:text="Select language"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing the `android:nextFocusUp` tag?

Comment: @PabloBaxter Problem still occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like ListView is taking focus and giving it to the first child when you tap on it. Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14945890/5318240). From the gist of it, you need to add the following in your activity on the manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

And add this to your ListView:

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```

Comment: This might be a secondary solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918494/edit-text-in-listactivity-listview-loses-focus-when-keyboard-comes-up/15294709#15294709

Comment: With second solution the problem still occur, but `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan` made the work. Thanks you soo much!