# SearchView with OneClick to enter text

Tags: android, searchview

In the android default search view, 2 clicks are required to input text for search as the first click is used to expand the editText view and another click is to set focus.

It seems to be q redundant and i want to reduce the process to one click only. Is there any methods to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two clicks happen if we put the searchView inside a ListView as the searchView lost focus after that. I suspect searchView behave a similar property with editText view in listView.

With reference to 
[Edit Text in ListActivity ListView loses focus when keyboard comes up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918494/edit-text-in-listactivity-listview-loses-focus-when-keyboard-comes-up)

and add the following codes in searchView xml
          android:focusable="true"
          android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

would get back the normal behavior of the searchView. Hope this will be useful to other people in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this behavior by calling

```
setIconifiedByDefault(false)
```

on your searchView.  Setting it to false will show the whole field.

Documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html).